# How to dynamically change image id value using flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, air

How can I dynamically change image id value?

ex:

```
<mx:Image id="test" source=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you're talking about something like this

```
<mx:Image id="test" />
```

And you want to change the id value.  Short answer is that you can't do that.  The id is the instance name of that image.  If you want to reference it in your actionscript that is what you use.

My guess is you just need some kind of identifier for the image though.  In that case, you should use something like the name property on the object to keep track of it.  So if you have lots of image objects, you can use the name property to keep track of them.